# React navigation and modal tab item

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Globally, I have the following structure in my app:

```
- StackNavigator
-- Item
-- Item
-- TabNavigator
--- Tab1
--- Tab2 => Want this one MODAL => new StackNavigator
---- EmptyScreen calling during DidMount ModalScreen as modal.
---- ModalScreen
--- Tab3
```

I would like the Tab2 being modal. From what I understood it's not possible to do that with TabNavigator from react-navigation so I have tried to tune the things by using another StackNavigator for tab2, mode as modal. Once the screen Tab2 is mounted I directly call the second screen which slides up correctly (modal). Probably not the best way to do. **I'm interested by any other suggestion.**

Now when I close this ModalScreen I would like to go back to Tab1 like if Tab2 screens were never called. I could use goBack() twice but how can I navigate to another tab screen and unmount completely Tab2 screens? **Any suggestion please?**

I'm not using Redux.

Thanks!